# File Loaded Into Memory Bigger than on Disk

Tags: java, memory, jtable, out-of-memory, memory-mapped-files

I am loading a text file in java into memory. The size of the text file is 100 MB and contains thousands of lines of either String, Integer, or Double type.

Once its loaded into memory though it is taking up an entire 1 GB or more if I compile using 64 bit JDK.

This is a problem because I need to load even bigger files.

They are stored as their exact data type in an arraylist. I looked at MemoryMappedFiles although I am not sure they would provide the functionality I require, the text files are tab deliminated with 40 columns that I need to display in a JTable, again I don't think I could use a memory mapped file if I need to display into a JTable but maybe I am wrong.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The Data is stored as follows, the reason I need all of it to be in memory is because at any point for purpose of calculations I need access to any of the rows in the file.

this is in my table model for the JTable, note the rowdata passed to the tablemodel is nulled out after to make sure there isnt a duplicate copy in memory

```
private Object[][] data;

public TableModel(ArrayList<String> headers, RowData[] importedData)
{                
   columnNames = new String[headers.size()];
   data = new Object[importedData.length][headers.size()];

   for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) // extract the column names
    {                                        // for the table
        this.columnNames[i] = headers.get(i);
    }

   for (int i = 0; i < importedData.length; i++)  // extracting the data
   {                                              // for the table
       for (int j = 0; j < headers.size(); j++)
       {
            this.data[i][j] = importedData[i].myList.get(j);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please upload the code for this

Comment: Waht is the memory structure use are using?

Comment: Do you need to load the entire file into memory?  Displaying 100MB of data in a single JTable sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I've added code, I don't necessarily need it all display at once, but need access to it if the user wants and for calculation purposes I may need access to any of the thousands of rows at any time when running the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using a lot of small objects in your memory structure. Probably that give you overhead. From my experience the best way to reduce memory consumption id use plain arrays. You can wrap this arrays to some other structure. When I use this approach it saves for me 70% of memmory. It is not clean code, but if you need save memory - it will work.

Also read data from file line-by-line. After next line was readed put this data into your structure.

For example if you need two fileds id and name you can create something like:

```
public class DataStructure {

    private final static int SIZE_STEP = 32;

    private int size = 0;
    private int[] ids = new int[SIZE_STEP];
    private String[] names = new String[SIZE_STEP];

    public void add(int id, String name) {
        if(size >= ids.length) {
            ids = Arrays.copyOf(ids, ids.length + SIZE_STEP);
            names = Arrays.copyOf(names, names.length + SIZE_STEP);
        }
        ids[size] = id;
        names[size] = name;
        size++;
    }

    public int getId(int index) {
        return ids[index];
    }

    public String getName(int index) {
        return names[index];
    }
}
```

Other approach can be a pagination. When you display only 20 records for example and provide a page navigation.

Answer (score 2):

> The size of the text file is 100 MB and contains thousands of lines of either String, Integer, or Double type.

No it doesn't. It contains thousands of lines of text which represent either strings, integers, or doubles, in text decimal format. There are no objects in a text file of any type whatsoever. So when you load it into memory and *convert* it into object format the memory usage is going to change.

> This is a problem because I need to load even bigger files.

So don't load them. Process them line by line, or paragraph by paragraph, whatever that means in your file, or use a database.

> the text files are tab deliminated with 40 columns that I need to display in a JTable

You don't need to display hundreds of megabytes of data in 40 columns in a `JTable.` That implies many thousands of rows. This is just a user interface nightmare. Unusable. Redesign your UI to use filters, redesign your data to use a database, redesign your application to load the filtered data and display it.

Answer (score 1):

I have already solved this problem on .NET platform, the reason will be probably same.

If you have let say string "hello" in the file on your hard drive it does not mean that `new String("hello")` occupies 2x5bytes also in memory.

In .NET new initialization of string took ~40bytes as there is couple of things regarding object definition itself in memory.

I've found nice article for java - http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml. It shows exact numbers

The same point is related to other types you mentioned. The only memory occupation **save** come into mind in number types like `int`.

The number `124567` in file is just string which takes 2xsize-of-string-representation,e.g. 2x7bytes in the case of UTF-8. On the other hand, an `int` instance in memory occupies 4 bytes.

Speaking of which, there is huge point in [binary serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) as it could save you a space in your hard drive.